# Como puedo obtener el estado de las aplicaciones que se estan ejecutando en android

Tags: android-asynctask

Como puedo obtener el estado de  las aplicaciones que se están ejecutando en android, favor agradezco si alguien me puede orientar o posee un ejemplo

Comment: Tienes que leer los procesos activos con _AcitivityManager_ (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) y aquí puedes ver una implementación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542326/android-how-to-get-the-processname-or-packagename-by-using-pid a mi me gusta ayudar y por eso te comento, pero te sugiero que borres la pregunta, pues no encaja con las normas del sitio o la edites para que cumpla con las normas y así, se te podrá responder con código que ayudará a otros usuarios.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imIojYM0xlk

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte y pronta respuesta pero te comento tengo el siguiente código que es casi el mismo de tu recomendación pero no me devuelve el nombre de la aplicación o aplicaciones  que se están ejecutando, si me puedes guiar o indicar que estoy haciendo mal te agradezco